# Defining order of columns in Postgresql full join without naming all columns

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm joining different tables with countries information, where one of them (`cty`) is the main table with the countries' names. All the tables have a column `c`, linking to the primary key in `cty` (also called `c`).

To join them all, I first used

```
select * from cty
full join table1 using (c)
full join table2 using (c)
```

This gives me all the countries in `cty`, but I want only the countries present in the other tables. To solve this, I tried

```
select * from table1
full join table2 using (c)
join cty using (c)
```

This solves the problem about the number of lines, but now the main columns are the last in the table.

Is there a way to keep the columns from `cty` in the beginning (left side) of the table without specifying all the column names of all tables (I have many tables), and keep only the lines present in the secondary tables?

Comment: Just use SELECT cty.*, table2.*

Comment: @h0mebrewer missing FROM-clause entry for table "cty"

Comment: Ah now I understood you @h0mebrewer. "select cty.*,table1.*,table2.* from table1 full join table2 using (c) full join cty using (c)". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from cty
         right join 
         (select * from table1
                   full join table2 using(id)
         ) fj on fj.id = tt1.id
;
```

Check it: http://rextester.com/HCA83570

Comment: Thanks, it works and is more concise than @h0mebrewer suggestion (each table is included only once).

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.